# What is meant by URL routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can any one explain me what URL routing is meant by? And try to give me small example also so that I can understand more.

Comment: Try to do a research before asking questions.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you write `http://www.example.com/sample`

and the browser opens

`http://www.example.com/sample.aspx`
or
`http://www.example.com/sample.php`

page then it would be called as URL Routing Rewriting

for example you can visit this link

http://intelliscence.co.uk/fd/

http://intelliscence.co.uk/fd/default.aspx

both link open the same page

Answer (score 1):

> The ASP.NET Routing module is responsible for mapping incoming browser requests to particular MVC controller actions.

I can give lot more explanation here, but you will benefit more from reading this article from Asp.net website :- [ASP.NET MVC Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)